# Add number to groups by count of values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe with a column I would like to group them by pack of 3 rows and then increment an indice on each pack.

```
id      protocol    protocol_grp
1       ISD     ISD1
2       ISD     ISD1
3       ISD     ISD1
4       IRQ     IRQ1
5       IRQ     IRQ1
6       IRQ     IRQ1
7       IRQ     IRQ2
8       IRQ     IRQ2
9       IRQ     IRQ2
10      IRQ     IRQ3
11      ISD     ISD2
12      ISD     ISD2
13      ISD     ISD2
14      ISD     ISD3
15      IRQ     IRQ3
16      IRQ     IRQ3
17      IRQ     IRQ4
```

The desired output is protocol_grp column.
What I'd like to be able to do is each time I had 3 same protocols, I increment the indice by 1.

Hopes this make sense.

Comment: Can you check the row id 16 please? It should be IRQ3 and not IRQ4, right?

Comment: @Corralien Right ! Corrected thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['protocol_grp'] = df['protocol'] + df.groupby('protocol').cumcount() \
                                        .floordiv(3).add(1).astype(str)
print(df)

# Output
    id protocol protocol_grp
0    1      ISD         ISD1
1    2      ISD         ISD1
2    3      ISD         ISD1
3    4      IRQ         IRQ1
4    5      IRQ         IRQ1
5    6      IRQ         IRQ1
6    7      IRQ         IRQ2
7    8      IRQ         IRQ2
8    9      IRQ         IRQ2
9   10      IRQ         IRQ3
10  11      ISD         ISD2
11  12      ISD         ISD2
12  13      ISD         ISD2
13  14      ISD         ISD3
14  15      IRQ         IRQ3
15  16      IRQ         IRQ3  # <- check this row
16  17      IRQ         IRQ4
```

Comment: I tried your solution with about 50k rows. But after a while (IRQ7 and ISD22) the indice start back to 1. I don't understand why

Comment: I have double checked; no leading or trailing whitespaces

Answer (score 1):

Let us check `cumcount` then get the divisor

```
df['protocol_grp'] = df['protocol'].add((df.groupby('protocol').cumcount()//3+1).astype(str))
```

Comment: Thx for you solution. But same as @Corralien, the indice is getting back to 1 after a while.